# net-snmp unable to translate numeric OID values to textual MIB name

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

When I run any commands such as:

```
# snmptranslate .1.3.6.1.4.1.28318.1.1.3
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3
# snmpwalk 58.196.58.149 1.3.6.1.4.1.28318.1.1.3
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3.1.0 = STRING: "89-14-a8-52-a4-46"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3.2.0 = STRING: "058.196.58.149/255.255.255.252"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3.3.0 = STRING: "058.196.58.149"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3.6.0 = STRING: "137.010.060.016"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3.7.0 = STRING: "137.010.060.017"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3.8.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3.9.0 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.28318.1.1.3.10.0 = STRING: "reserved"
```

I would like `net-snmp` to translate `.1.3.6.1.4.1.28318.1.1.3` to the textual MIB formats. I'm not sure how to debug this.

I have this in my `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`:

```
# cat /etc/snmp/snmp.conf
mibdirs /usr/share/snmp/mibs
defVersion 2c
defCommunity public
```

Where all my MIBs are in `/usr/share/snmp/mibs`. I know that `1.3.6.1.4.1.28318.1.1.3.0` corresponds to a textual MIB name of `mac` representing the mac address.

Any idea how to debug what has gone wrong and fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `net-snmp` doesn't load MIBs even if they're specified in the MIB directory.

So by adding `mibs` to the `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` file fixed it:

```
# cat /etc/snmp/snmp.conf
mibdirs /usr/share/snmp/mibs
mibs +MYMIB
defVersion 2c
defCommunity public
```

The OID is translated properly. This can also be debugged by doing a:

```
$ snmptranslate -m +MYMIB -IR -On hello
MYMIB::hello = STRING: "WORLD"
```

Which will either output correctly above or show an issue. Note the `-m +MYMIB` doesn't have to be there if in the `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` file.